# Video blinks in and out

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I'm using the raspbian installer. When I get to the step to select disk partitioning the video display starts to blink in and out.

At first it just blinks a few times and progresses to the point where it's just off. I can only get video by repeatedly switching consoles, but even then it only flashes briefly.

I have the Pi attached to a 70" HDMI 1080p TV (it is seriously the smallest thing I have available).

My first thought is that perhaps there's not enough video memory allocated. I'm just starting to research this but I figured I'd ask to see if this is a common before I jump in and spend potentially a few days on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is low power from the USB cable. Low quality cables will cause attinuation and won't supply enough power to drive HDMI.

Switching to the RCA video jack or a higher quality USB cable will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using less than 64MB GPU memory on a full HD display, I was having massive problems. Running headless or with console only, I was successful in using only 16MB GPU memory. So, if you are running X11, you should leave the GPU/CPU split at the default 64MB.

Comment: I'm trying to install raspbian. So it's ncurses based right now.

Comment: Have you tried changing the memory split anyway?

Comment: I haven't done anything to change it. I read that the default is 64M. I'm also not yet sure how to change the split on the installer. I could bump it to 128M. And I assume I place `config.txt` along with the rest of the boot files.

Comment: Ok, I figured from you question that you might have changed the setting, but I think you should be fine. Maybe the problem is then with the TV? Try taking the Pi to a friend and hooking it up to some LCD computer display with HDMI input (or using a HDMI to DVI cable/adapter).